# jsf Trinidad: Change tr:table header

Tags: java, jsf, trinidad

I have a tr:table with the rowSelection property set to "single". It draws a extra column with a radio buttons inside. But I want to change the text displayed at that column's header. I don't find any property that allow me to accomplish this. I guess I should overwrite some properties file but I haven't found anything on this topic in the Trinidad documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As Trinidad itself doesn't seem to offer this, you can do it with javascript. It is not a clean solution, but it will work.
First, open the generated html code and find the  in which you are interested. If it has an ID - `document.getElementById("yourformname:tdId")`. If it doesn't, try accessing it with `getElementsByTagName("td")` called on the table. When you have it, set its `innerHTML` to whatever text you want.
It is an ugly workaround, but will possibly work

Comment: Thanks for your help, Bozho. I have thought this before but I was looking for a more elegant way to change the column text. I guess I'll have to do something like you say though.
+1 for giving a workaround.

Comment: Perhaps you can dig into Trinidad source code and modify it to fit your needs. I looked through it a bit and noticed a so called SpecialColumn class that is used for the column you said. You will have to add a property to the component, and modify the renderer a bit. Not easy anyway, but more elegant than a JS solution :)